# What is a way to estimate job match quality using new job wage, old job, wage, and how long a new job was had?

Tags: inference, dataset, descriptive-statistics

The data I have seeks to understand whether an individual's new job is of high quality. I have an individuals

`old job wage: how much they were paid before`,

`new job wage: how much they were paid in new job`, and

`new job duration: how many days they are in the new job before quitting or going somewhere else`.

I would like to use these metrics to come up with a measure of how good the new job is. Ideas I had included

1. Relative change of old and new job wage
2. Combining 1) Relative Change with `new job duration`

Is there a way I can use these 3 variables to measure new job quality? Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of *quality of a job*?